# How to tell if Queue size is greater than max int?

Tags: java, collections, int, queue, max

Is there a way to get the size of a java.util.Queue whose size exceeds max int without having to build a wrapper around it? Any other libraries may be?

Comment: Do you mean `java.util.Queue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
    long size = 0;
    for(Iterator i = queue.iterator(); i.hasNext(); i.next()) {
        size++;
    }
    return size > Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I don't think you can, at least not without modifying the queue.

The `size` method inherited from collections will return maxint if there are more elements than that but it will also return that if there are *exactly* that many elements.

So, other than extracting an element and seeing if the size changes, there's no other way.

That doesn't stop you creating your own queue (with a `long` size) if it's really important.

However, I've seen very few cases in my long career where queues ever get that big - you *may* want to rethink what you're doing, they're may be a better way.

Comment: hmm.. I think that should be good enough for me. 
Do you happen to know of any other collection type that allows this?

Comment: I'm using it in a unit test to check the amount of data collected. If it returns max int for size greater than that, I think that should solve my purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In theory yes.  You could use nasty reflection to break abstraction and dig around in the queue's implementation data structures.  But that is a really bad idea.

If you really need queues that size, then you almost certainly need a custom queue class<sup>1</sup>.  At that point, you can easily include a custom getter in your API to retrieve a 64 bit queue size.

---

<sup>1 - An queue backed by a simple array won't be able to support more that 2^31 - 1 elements, and a linked queue with that number of elements is going to waste many gigabytes of memory ... not to mention causing major indigestion for the GC.</sup>